# SaveChanges() как работает?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

При использовании на контексте `SaveChanges()` или `SaveChangesAsync()` после добавления какого-то элемента в экземпляр контекста изменения сохраняются только после перезапуска приложения. Мне казалось, что после `db.Table.Add(Element)` и `db.SaveChanges()` в следующей строке я бы мог достать этот элемент, но почему-то нет.

Answer (score 2):

грубо :

```
Student student = new Student();
student.Name = "Student";

context.Students.Add(student);
context.SaveChanges();

Console.WriteLine(student.Id);
```

Id не будет пустым.

Comment: Т.е. данные сразу же сохраняются? Мне надо было это знать, чтобы  понять где искать ошибку, спасибо

Comment: @SergG это будет работать если database генерит ID's самостоятельно, а-ля Identity в MS SQL

Comment: @SergG можете обратиться к этому ресурсу, тут достаточно информации для работы с Entity (https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level3/3_8.php)